# Postgresql: How to convert JSONb keys into an ENUM list?

Tags: database, postgresql, enums, jsonb

I'm currently cleaning some tables in our application, and we have some JSONb defined in some tables, whose values are just `true` or `false` for a given key. Seeing that, i want to get rid of the jsonb, to have instead an **enum array**, in which i could get the former keys of my jsonb (whose value was true)

For instance, i want to transform this table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   ...
   my_field   JSONB
   ...
);
```

to

```
CREATE TYPE field_enum AS ENUM (
   'key1',
   'key2',
   'key3',
   'key4',
   'key5',
   'key6'
);

CREATE TABLE my_table (
   ...
   my_field   field_enum[] DEFAULT NULL,
   ...
);
```

And i want the data to be migrated from (for this example)

```
{"key1": true, "key2": null, "key3": false, "key4": true}
```

to

```
['key1','key4']
```

I'm trying to alter my colum type by doing the data migration by a unique command, which i think could be something of:

```
ALTER TABLE
    my_table
    ALTER COLUMN
        my_field
    TYPE
        field_enum
    USING __XXXXXX___;
```

The `using` part is where i have difficulties, anybody has an idea of how i should alter my column without losing data?

I'm also open to create a new field and rename it after that, and use an UPDATE on the table.

I was thinking of using the `jsonb_object_keys` function but it first gives me all keys, and not just those whose values are true, and it also gives me an record[] which i don't manage to cast as a enum[].

Even more deeper, but it is not mandatory for me as i can do it as a post-treatment, it may happen that the json keys has to be linked to a enum key that is not the same, lets say that `key1` should be converted as `NEW_KEY`(upper_case and name changing). Do you think it's possible to include in the same postgresql command?

If anybody of you has an idea of what i could do, i would appreciate any help.

Thanks !

X.

Comment: Why don't you completely unroll that and just have 6 Boolean columns? That'd be way easier to query for such flags.

Comment: I thought about this idea, but given i have 6 JSONB on my table, and around 10 keys by JSONB, an given that we have a react dropdown component that takes ENUM list easily as inputs, it is very convenient and readeable to have 6 ENUM[] fields instead of 60 fields on my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function to convert a json object to your enum array:

```
create or replace function jsonb_to_field_enums(jsonb)
returns field_enum[] language sql immutable
as $$
    select array_agg(key)::field_enum[]
    from jsonb_each_text($1)
    where value::bool
$$;
```

[Db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e1f88a5a59b8e05e3f5f6a399937cb8)

Comment: oh great, that works perfectly ! With this method, i can easily define a new fields and use an UPDATE on my table to get the values in my new field, then drop my former JSONB field and rename the new one by the former field name. Thats works.

By any chance, do you know if i can use this method directly in a `USING`, so that i can avoid the part where i add a new field?

Comment: Of course, you can use it in `alter table`. You didn't seem to notice the link to [Db<>fidlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e1f88a5a59b8e05e3f5f6a399937cb8)
 at the bottom of the answer. Click it to see the full example.

Comment: Ahah yes you are right,  i did not see the link ! That works perfectly well ! Thank you for your help ! appreciate it ! <3